# How can I define 'TEXT' type using eBean in Play! framework?

Tags: database, playframework-2.0, ebean

When I define a variable in Model class as a String, it is converted as 'VARCHAR(255)' in DB.

However, I want to save more than 255 because this data is very long text consisting of several paragraphs.

As far as I remember, there is a TEXT type in DB to save very long text.

How can I define TEXT type in Play! framework?

I tried Constraints.MaxLength and Constraints.Max defined in Play! framework api.

However, still 1.sql file (created by Ebean DDL automatically) defines this variable as VARCHAR(255).

Thanks, in advance!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In your model, just use the column definition set as `TEXT`:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity extends Model {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String aLongText;
    ....

}
```

I already used it with Postgres, don't know if it is ok with other database server.

Comment: It is not correct for Oracle for example. An alternative there is "Clob"

Answer (score 9):

You could use the `@Lob` annotation on your field which will yield type `longtext` on MySQL and type `text` on PostgreSQL:

```
package models;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Lob;

@Entity
public class Foo {

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @Lob
    public String bar;

}
```

in MySQL this yields:

```
mysql> describe foo;
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| bar   | longtext   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

in PostgreSQL this yields:

```
foodb=> \d foo;
     Table "public.foo"
 Column |  Type  | Modifiers
--------+--------+-----------
 id     | bigint | not null
 bar    | text   |
Indexes:
    "pk_foo" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

According to the [Java EE api](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Lob.html):

> The Lob type is inferred from the type of the persistent field or property

Which means that a field of type `String` should give you some text blob and a field of type `byte[]` should give you some binary blob.

Comment: I tried this answer first, but as of 2017-02-02 with Ebean 9.3.1 with MySQL 5.7.17, `@Lob` yields `longblob` instead of `longtext`.  Will that work with UTF-8?  I think I'll go DB specific with `@Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")` instead.